# Sum of count records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using sql server 2008 R2. I am having a table in database that contains data regarding patients that are of different status like Active, Completed, Inactive etc. I am asked to get the patients with "Active" status group by date.

I have created following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalActivePatients, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111) AS CreatedDtUTC
FROM TablePatient 
WHERE MonitoringStatus LIKE 'Active' 
AND IsDeleted=0
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)
```

and that gives me the result like below :

```
TotalActivePatients CreatedDtUTC
1                   2013/02/24
2                   2013/02/25
4                   2013/02/28
4                   2013/03/01
1                   2013/03/06
1                   2013/03/10
3                   2013/03/11
2                   2013/03/14
3                   2013/03/15
2                   2013/03/16
```

But, It is giving me the number of active patients on specific date. I want the sum of total active patients upto that specific date.

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the desired result and what is the underlying sample data for the result above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Look, in 2013/02/24 there is 1 patient active, on 2013/02/25 it shows there are 2 patients active, but the patient of previous record i.e 2013/02/24 is also in active status on that date, so the sum should be 3, but as I am applying group by, this is showing only 2 patients that are created on that specific date, are active.

Comment: I didn't look at this very long......(thus why a comment and not an answer), but check my example here:  http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/cte-running-total-example/

Comment: I just updated my example.  Wordpress butchered my original formatting.  It should work now, as is.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the running total...

```
SELECT  DISTINCT COUNT(1) OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)), 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111) AS CreatedDtUTC
FROM    TablePatient 
WHERE   MonitoringStatus = 'Active' 
AND     IsDeleted = 0
```

Comment: PS: A like without wildcards is an `=`, might as well use it for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer will be the following:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111) AS CreatedDtUTC,
     COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)), 

FROM    TablePatient 
WHERE   MonitoringStatus = 'Active' 
AND     IsDeleted = 0
ORDER BY 1
```

Additional info according to using `OVER` clause can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx